# In CSS layouts what is the means of word "Faux column"?

Tags: css

In CSS layouts what is the means of word "Faux column"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "fake column".  The French word [faux](http://tfd.com/faux) translates roughly to *false* or *fake*.

The idea behind the [faux columns technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) was to allow developers to create columns that appear to stretch the full height of the viewport without resorting to a table-based layout.

Answer (score 3):

Using a vertically-tiled background image to make a column appear as though it extends to the bottom of a page.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/